# How to create a pivot table in pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a dataframe ‘annual_stats’ that I need to reshape into a pivot table. Attached you can see what it currently looks like and what it is supposed to look like after reshaping.
[what the dataframe is currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NWeO.jpg)

[what it needs to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tHHd.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two possible ways to achieve this,

```
annual_stats.groupby(['state', 'year'])['salary'].sum().unstack()

pd.pivot_table(annual_stats, values='salary', index='state', columns='year', aggfunc='mean')
```